# inherent curve in rhino python

Tags: python, rhino3d

Using rhino python to write scripts in rhino.

I am trying to inherent the curve object.

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino 

class MyCurve(Rhino.Geometry.Curve):
    def __init__(self, pnt):
        Rhino.Geometry.Curve.__init__(self)
        self = rs.AddCurve(pnt)

rc = MyCurve([[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
print rs.CurveLength(rc)
```

To add my own def to the class.

What to inherent from?
Rhino.Geometry.Curve is just a place holder since I do not know what to inherent from.

Know that rs.AddCurve(pnt) return a guid object.

The method hat I am using at the moment is.

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino 

class MyCurve():
    curve = None
    def __init__(self, pnt):
        self.curve = rs.AddCurve(pnt)

rc = MyCurve([[0,0,0],[1,0,0]])
print rs.CurveLength(rc.curve)
```

But I think that there much be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You typically don't ever inherit from the geometry classes in RhinoCommon (classes like Rhino.Geometry.Curve).  What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I like to add my own def to curve class. So I do not need to make wrapper classes and index into them. Like A = MyCurve()     A.curve. But you did not really answer my question, just asked me one back. Do you know how to do it?